# Is my understanding of free group correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Let $(G,*)$ be a group.

Let $S$ be a subset of $G$.

Then, construct the free group $(F(S),*')$ on $S$.

If there exists an isomorphism $\phi:(G,*)\rightarrow (F(S),*')$ such that $\phi(s)=(s)$ on $S$, then we say "$(G,*)$ is free on $S$".

Is my understanding correct? I'm asking this because several books have distinct definitions(i.e. fraleigh and Dummit&Foote)

Comment: @Dietrich I said it to emphsize that $*$ does not affect anything on construcing $F(S)$ on $S$. Does $*$ affect construction on $F(S)$?

Comment: @Dietrich I don't think I get it.. Do you mean that $*$ affects the construction of $F(S)$?

Comment: @Dietrich Thank you I got it. Except that, is everything else correct?

Comment: Yes. Check also the description [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group). It says that "An arbitrary group $G$ is called free if it is isomorphic to $F(S)$ for some subset $S$ of $G$."

Comment: @Dietrich So do you mean that I can remove "$\phi(s)=s$ on $S$" hypothesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read that as correct. As another way of looking at it: If $G$ is a free group generated by the set $S$, then the universal map from $F(S)$ to $G$ will be a surjective isomorphism. The inverse of this map will exactly be the map $\phi$.

Granted, it is possible for $G$ to be free without this being satisfied, depending on how you choose $S$: For example, let $G = \mathbb{Z}$, and let $S = \{2\}$. Then the free group on $S$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$ again, and the universal map $F(S) \to G$ is the inclusion $2\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. This of course does not have an inverse.

This doesn't contradict anything that you've said, of course; $\mathbb{Z}$ is *not* free on the set $\{2\}$. More an idle comment, I guess.

Comment: What do you mean "the free group on $S$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$ again"? Isn't the free group on $S$, $2\mathbb{Z}$ as you said?

Comment: Yes, but those two groups are isomorphic. A free group on one generator is always isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$; more generally, up to isomorphism there is a unique free group on any fixed number of generators.